# text is not a function error when going through array of promises

Tags: javascript

```
function haePosti(i) {
    let postilup = fetch('http://localhost:8080/postit/' + i);
    return postilup;
}
async function tekstiPosti() {
    var luku = await muokkaaLuku();
    var lupaukset = [];
    var lupaukset2 = []
    var postit = [];
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < luku; i++) {
        lupaukset.push(haePosti(i));
    }

    Promise.all(lupaukset).then(()=>{
        for (i = 0; i < luku; i++) {
            console.log(lupaukset[i]);
            lupaukset[i] = lupaukset[i].text().then(function(text) {
                postit[i] = text.replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, '');
                console.log(postit[i]);
            });
        }
    }
    );
    return postit;

}
```

I have written an node API, from where I try to fetch() data and modify it. It all goes well until I have to start to alter the return value. In console it shows that it pushes the promises all normal to the array and even resolves them after promise.all() command, but when I try to start alter the values it either complains the following

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3DzJ.jpg)

I am relatively new to the web programming and only few weeks fresh with node and js. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: You don't await the Promise.all, or use the array of resolved values it provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `text` on a *promise*, not the *fulfillment value* of the promise. You need to use the array that `Promise.all` provides as its fulfillment value, not `lupaukset`.

But there are some other problems:

- You're not checking for HTTP success of your `fetch` calls (the `fetch` API footgun)
- You're returning your `postit` array before it has anything in it, because it's filled in by the fulfillment handler of `Promise.all` but your function doesn't wait for that before returning

See comments:

```
async function haePosti(i){
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/postit/'+i);
    // Handle the `fetch` footgun
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    // Request the text of the body
    return response.text();
}
async function tekstiPosti(){
    const luku = await muokkaaLuku();
    var lupaukset = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < luku; ++i) {
        lupaukset.push(haePosti(i));
    }
    
    // Wait for the results
    const postit = await Promise.all(lupaukset);

    // Map them through your `replace` and return the result
    return postit.map(text => text.replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, '');
}
```